# Unity3d Steamworks is not initialized

Tags: unity-game-engine, porting, steam, steamworks-api

I am doing a unity project for Steam. So I downloaded and added SteamWorks.net to the project created an empty object and attached the steam manager code to that. And for the achievements, in the script, import steam using

```
'using Steamworks;'
```

And set achievements using

```
SteamUserStats.SetAchievement(); 
SteamUserStats.StoreStats();
```

Now when I run the code I am getting an error

> 'Steamworks is not initialized".

how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

When testing make sure the steam_appid.txt is in the folder. SteamManager monobehaviour will initialize API on awake.

Answer (score 0):

Also this worked for me and I felt kind of dumb but it's important.  Double check to make sure your steam app is currently logged in.  If your turned on your computer and it logged you out or if there was an update or something that requires you to log in than it wont work and it'll throw that error.  Otherwise you should be good if you listened to the other answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a VR game.
You have to make sure you followed this steps:

1. You have a Steam Manager script that you have executed and waited to intialize.
2. Inside your Steam Manager script make sure that you placed your Steam app id
   here:

   ```
    if (SteamAPI.RestartAppIfNecessary((AppId_t)345689)) {
        Debug.Log("[Steamworks.NET] Shutting down because RestartAppIfNecessary returned true. Steam will restart the application.");

        Application.Quit();
        return;
    }
   ```
3. You have the file "steam_appid.txt" with your app id inside on the root folder of the project (not in the Assets folder, instead in the folder that contains the Assets folder).
4. You are Logged in on your Steam account (your steam user will be take as the test user).
5. You have redeemed a copy of the game on Steam if you are not using the same account that you used to publish the game.

Doing this you can test for example the Leaderboard api inside Unity without publishing the game, in my personal case I am developing a VR game and it was not necesary to run SteamVR to make this test, I was able to test the with a VR simulator.